# Quitting to start my own company

Tags: job-change, quitting

I've been working at my current job for over 9 months now, and it's been great. However, I've started learning more about the world of Software Consulting, and I have close to 4 clients lined up for a Consulting company I recently started.

So, I've decided to quit my current job to focus on my company. The only thing I'm concerned about is this:

I'll be using the skills I learned at work (Javascript, JQuery, etc...) for my contracting work.

Is there any problem with using skills I learned at work to form my own company?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Are you worried about legal action?

Comment: What problems are you expecting and where are you at.  The answer is completely different in China than it is in the US

Comment: I am voting to keep it closed because the OP is not disclosing which country the OP works in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any problem with using skills I learned at work to form my
>   own company?

No.

When you form your own company, you are allowed to bring all of your skills to bear - without regard to where you learned them (at least in the US).

You aren't free to bring code with you, nor are you usually free to bring clients with you, and sometimes there are restrictions such as "trade secrets", and sometimes the contract and/or non-compete agreement limits how you can proceed.

But for the most part the knowledge in your head is yours forever to use as you desire.

Comment: I will also add you should make sure you don't utilize what your previous company could consider "Trade secrets" or using privileged knowledge obtained from your past company. (Basically if your company did something in a truly unique way, you probably need to be careful about doing the same)

Answer (score 7):

Check what you signed when you hired on. There may be noncompete clauses in the contract which restrict what you can do for some specific time after leaving the company.

Other than that, as long as you aren't abusing inside knowledge about your past employer, there isn't an issue.

I'm trying very hard to avoid commenting on "9 months".